# Как заставить сервис включиться строго при наличии доступа в Интернет?

Tags: linux, сеть, systemd

Столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть сервис, который должен стартовать из systemd при загрузке. Заставить его загружаться при относительно штатной загрузке, а также из-под emergency mode я смог. Но дело в том, что он стартует раньше сетевых демонов systemd, которые выдают доступ в Интернет. А моему демону желательно стартовать строго после них

```
[Unit]
Description=Nothing
[Service]
ExecStart=/root/systemd/main
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
After=networking.service NetworkManager-wait-online.service
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targer emergency.target
```

cmdline такой, так что я вижу логи:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.7 ro
```

И мой сервис стартует до запуска сетевых сервисов. Как это исправить - либо из самого systemd, либо как проверить выход в Интернет на C++ (исполняемый файл - C++ программа)?

Comment: Надо запускать в hook-скриптах для сетевого интерфейса, который подключен к интернет. ifup ifdown - что-то такое.

Comment: идея хорошая, но дело в том, что это должно работать строго при запуске системы. Т е, если я вручную буду включать/отключать выход в интернет, демон стартовать НЕ ДОЛЖЕН

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After строчка пишется в раделе `[Unit]`, но возможно Вам нужен Requires

```
[Unit]
Description=Nothing
Requires=NetworkManager-wait-online.service

[Service]
```

Проверку реального интернета проще сделать на bash скрипте и поставить его в `ExecPre=/usr/local/bin/check-online.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
while ! wget -O/dev/null http://gstatic.com/generate_204; do sleep 10; done;
```

Можно использовать ping или дёргать ресурс вашего приложения

Comment: не помогло. Боюсь, выход один - проверять доступ в интернет напрямую из исполняемого файла...

Comment: попробуй так...